# I am trying to have users authenticate my app with OAuth2.0, but the external site requires the redirect url(uri?) to conform to https

Tags: ios, swift, oauth

The API I am trying to access is Ebay's.

How do I handle this through IOS, do I need to register a site?

How do I have the user redirect back to my app after giving my application permissions to access their data? I thought I could just use my bundle identifier as my redirect. Am I thinking about this all wrong?

I followed the [Auth0 tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/get-started-ios-authentication-swift-swiftui-part-1-login-logout/) to understand the OAuth protocol but registering my app through them I am able to put redirect uri as my bundle identifier, and they provide me a domain so that my application can communicate with their backend.

Comment: The url you must define is an url that could be used to open your app from any app on the device. It is different form your bundle id. You need to define an url scheme in your app. Look at Apple [AuthentificationServices](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you're after is universal linking: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/allowing-apps-and-websites-to-link-to-your-content It allows you to tie a URL to your application so that when a redirect occurs on your mobile phone, the browser will open the associated mobile app. This way you can register a HTTPS redirect URI for your mobile app client.